# Split a string variable when using fancyhead in Latex

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using `fancyhdr` for my reports class. I store the name of the assignment in a variable. Then I place its contents in the top-right of each page except the first one. Besides the top-right I also have a top-left and a center header. If the assignment text is long it overlaps with the center header as you can see in the picture.

[image]

```
% Header and footer style.
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.7pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{followingpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,LO]{\@student}
  \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\@course}
  \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\@assignment}
  \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.7pt}
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to split the contents of the variable `@assignment` so that it shows in two or more lines and prevents this overlapping.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* minimum working example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  You are more likely to get assistance the easier you make it on the volunteer "helpers."

Comment: That is, we would like [one of these](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), please. In particular, it is pretty hard to help without any clue how those commands are defined, or how you want the strings to be split.

Comment: Put `@assignment` inside a `\parbox` or `minipage`.